# How to append an array to an array in Redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

Say I have the following condition in the reducer:

```js
    case POST_LOAD_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            posts: [...payload]
        }
```

This action contains an array as payload `[{post_1},{post_2},{post_3},{post4},{post5}]`. Now if this action is fired again what happens is that the previous payload is replaced by the new one, which is correct behavior.
What I want to do is to append the next call into the previous `posts` array! So say if the post array is already the following:

```js
posts: [
    {post_1},
    {post_2},
    {post_3},
    {post_4},
    {post_5}
];
```

Now as more data arrives I want that new data to be appended to this post again (no matter the size, by this I mean that if the new array does not contain 5 elements):

```js
posts: [
    {post_1},
    {post_2},
    {post_3},
    {post_4},
    {post_5},
    {post_6},
    {post_7},
    {post_8},
    {post_9},
    {post_10}
];
```

Now only if this was in React state this could have been done by using previous states the redux part causes the trouble for me!

Comment: if your previous state has a posts key, you can use [...state, ...payload], or maybe [...state.posts, ...payload].

Comment: @YasserZubair Yes this can be done! However what about the other side of it? Do you see any way this can cause problems! Since we're using state directly! Btw this is a great solution in itself!

Comment: @YasserZubair Can you post your comment as an answer! I would mark it as an answer so that people can refer to it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: this wont mutate the state so no side effects that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your previous state has a posts key, you can use:

```
[...state, ...payload]
```

or maybe

```
[...state.posts, ...payload]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the same way you are passing the payload. You can pass multiple arrays while doing array de-structuring.

```
case POST_LOAD_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            posts: [...state.posts, ...payload]
        }
```